# Get data from Folder Power Query not updating charts and graphs

Tags: excel, charts, directory, powerquery, auto-update

I'm trying to create a sheet in Excel with charts and graphs, my main goal is get the data from another excel file in a folder but this file we gonna call it `filetoreplace.xlxs` contains data for one area and it will be replaced, it's a survey but it will contain data from diferent cities every 3 months it's an analysis for a city but each city needs a different dashboard so I need to find a way to change the data only replacing the file, I tried with power query in excel with get data from folder but when I replace the file I have an error I would like some help with this because I tried different tutorials in Youtube and I haven't success.

UPDATE 1 (QUERY EDITOR FORMULA):

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"Response ID", Int64.Type}, {"Date submitted", type datetime}, {"Last page", Int64.Type}, {"Start language", type text}, {"Seed", Int64.Type}, {"Access code", type text}, {"Date started", type datetime}, {"Date last action", type datetime}, {"A) INSTITUTIONAL OVERVIEW", type any}, {"1. What best describes your facility/hospital?", type text}, {"1. What best describes your facility/hospital? [Other]", type text}, {"1.1 Please select Mono-specialised centre type?", type any}, {"2. Is your facility/hospital public or private?", type text}, {"2. Is your facility/hospital public or private? [Other]", type any}, {"3. Is your facility/hospital a university teaching facility/hospital?", type text}, {"4. Does your facility/hospital have a formal research programme for cancer?", type text}, {"5. Does your facility/hospital have ongoing collaboration(s) for research in cancer care?", type text}, {"5.1 Please list the names of your national university/educational or research partners [University / Partner 1]", type text}, {"5.1 Please list the names of your national university/educational or research partners [University / Partner 2]", type text}, {"5.1 Please list the names of your national university/educational or research partners [University / Partner 3]", type text}, {"5.1 Please list the names of your national university/educational or research partners [University / Partner 4]", type any}, {"5.1 Please list the names of your national university/educational or research partners [University / Partner 5]", type any}, {"6. Does your facility/hospital have a partnership with any other local/national health facilities?", type text}, {"6.1 Please list the names of the local/national health facilities that your facility/hospital has partnerships with", type text}, {"7. Does your facility/hospital have a partnership with international organisations on cancer? (e.g. counterpart for international research, technical cooperation project, receiving teaching projects)", type text}, {"7.1 Please list the name(s) of your facility/hospital’s international organisation partners", type any}, {"8. Do you have a functional Ethics Committee for cancer care at your facility/hospital? ", type text}, {"8.1 How often does the Ethics Committee meet?", type text})
```

Comment: Please paste your current M code (Edit query, advanced editor, copy all from that window and paste here and mark the pasted code as being code)

Comment: @jkpieterse check the UPDATE 1 the full formula is about 21012 characters but is not posible to paste all in the stackoverflow

Comment: Maybe these pages help? https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Power-Query-fails-when-column-does-not-exist/td-p/936783 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/handling-data-source-errors-power-query-7b0b4a6e-9402-4f80-ab66-2239dbc7d6e8 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/dealing-with-errors